# Fetch 2 different columns same data in 2 different rows

Tags: mysql, oracle, query

I have an issue and got stuck very badly.

I have a table `product` which has 5 columns:

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
```

There are a few records where the same value is repeated in different columns and in different rows like this:

```
 ID | col1  | col2  | col3  | col4  | col5
----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
 1  | demo1 | demo2 | demo3 | demo4 | demo5
 2  | demo2 | demo1 | demo5 | demo4 | demo3
```

Now I want to retrieve all the records where the `col1` value and `col2` value are same (e.g. `demo1`) even over multiple rows (e.g. row 1 and row 2).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show desired output form.

Comment: To do SQL in any sane way it has to be structured. Is correcting the variance of structure possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM product AS a
    JOIN product AS b  ON a.col1 = b.col2
```

If this presents too many rows, then I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to provide filtering to avoid, for example, displaying a row in which `col1 = col2` all by itself.